# View only two weeks in the month using Calenderio

Tags: javascript, calendar

I am trying to display a two week view using Calenderio. So for example it should display 4/19/2015 - 5/2/2015, not the entire month of April. I am confused as to where in the JS I have to modify it to display only two weeks.

**Here is the JS:**

```
function($, window, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    $.Calendario = function(options, element) {
        this.$el = $(element);
        this._init(options);
    };

    // the options
    $.Calendario.defaults = {
        /*
  you can also pass:
  month : initialize calendar with this month (1-12). Default is today.
  year : initialize calendar with this year. Default is today.
  caldata : initial data/content for the calendar.
  caldata format:
  {
    'MM-DD-YYYY' : 'HTML Content',
    'MM-DD-YYYY' : 'HTML Content',
      ...
  }
*/
        weeks: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
        weekabbrs: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        monthabbrs: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        displayWeekAbbr: false, // choose between values in options.weeks or options.weekabbrs
        displayMonthAbbr: false, // choose between values in options.months or options.monthabbrs
        startIn: 0, // left most day in the calendar (0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday, ... , 6 - Saturday)
        events: 'click',
        fillEmpty: true,
        feedParser: './feed/',
        zone: '00:00', // Ex: IST zone time is '+05:30' by default it is GMT, Sign is important.
        checkUpdate: true //Check if any new version of Calendario is released (Details will be in the browser console)
    };

    $.Calendario.prototype = {
        _init: function(options) {
            // options
            this.VERSION = '3.2.0';
            this.UNIQUE = '%{unique}%'; //UNIQUE helps us differentiate your js from others and help us keep a track of run time.
            this.options = $.extend(true, {}, $.Calendario.defaults, options);
            this.today = new Date();
            this.month = (isNaN(this.options.month) || this.options.month === null) ? this.today.getMonth() : this.options.month - 1;
            this.year = (isNaN(this.options.year) || this.options.year === null) ? this.today.getFullYear() : this.options.year;
            this.caldata = this._processCaldata(this.options.caldata);
            // if hover is passed as an event then throw error if jQuery is 1.9 or above 1.9, because, hover psuedo name isn't supported
            if (parseFloat($().jquery) >= 1.9 && this.options.events.indexOf('hover') != -1)
                this.logError('\'hover\' psuedo-name is not supported' + ' in jQuery 1.9+. Use \'mouseenter\' \'mouseleave\' events instead.');

            this.options.events = this.options.events.split(',');
            this.options.zone = this.options.zone.charAt(0) != '+' && this.options.zone.charAt(0) != '-' ? '+' + this.options.zone : this.options.zone;
            this._generateTemplate(true);
            this._initEvents();
        },

        _processCaldataObj: function(val, key) {
            if (typeof val !== 'object') val = {
                content: val,
                startTime: '00:00',
                endTime: '23:59',
                allDay: true
            };
            if (!val.content) this.logError('Content is missing in date ' + key);
            if (val.startTime && !val.endTime) val.endTime = parseInt(val.startTime.split(':')[0]) + 1 + ':' + val.startTime.split(':')[1];
            if (!val.startTime && !val.endTime) val = $.extend({}, val, {
                startTime: '00:00',
                endTime: '23:59',
                allDay: true
            });
            if (val.startTime && val.endTime && val.allDay === undefined) val.allDay = false;
            if (/^\d{2}-DD-\d{4}/.test(key) || /^\d{2}-DD-YYYY/.test(key)) {
                var det = /^(\d{2})-DD-(\d{4})/.exec(key) || /^(\d{2})-DD-YYYY/.exec(key),
                    chkDate;
                if (det.length == 3) chkDate = new Date(det[2], det[1], 0);
                else if (det.length == 2) chkDate = new Date(this.year, det[1], 0)
                if (!val.startDate) val.startDate = 1;
                if (!val.endDate && chkDate.getDate() != 1) val.endDate = chkDate.getDate();
                if (!val.endDate && chkDate.getDate() == 1 && det.length == 3) val.endDate = chkDate.getDate();
            }
            return val;
        },

        _processCaldata: function(caldata) {
            var self = this;
            caldata = caldata || {};
            $.each(caldata, function(key, val) {
                if (/^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/.test(key) || /^\d{2}-\d{2}-YYYY/.test(key) || /^\d{2}-DD-YYYY/.test(key) || /^MM-\d{2}-YYYY/.test(key) ||
                    /^\d{2}-DD-YYYY/.test(key) || /^MM-\d{2}-\d{4}/.test(key) || /^\d{2}-DD-\d{4}/.test(key) || key == 'TODAY') {} else
                    self.logError(key + ' is an Invalid Date. Date should not contain spaces, should be separated by \'-\' and should be in the ' +
                        'format \'MM-DD-YYYY\'. That ain\'t that difficult!');
                if (Array.isArray(val)) {
                    $.each(val, function(i, c) {
                        val[i] = self._processCaldataObj(c, key);
                    });
                    caldata[key] = val;
                } else {
                    caldata[key] = self._processCaldataObj(val, key);
                }
            });
            return caldata;
        },

        _propDate: function($cell, event) {
            var idx = $cell.index(),
                data = {
                    allDay: [],
                    content: [],
                    endTime: [],
                    startTime: []
                },
                dateProp = {
                    day: $cell.children('span.fc-date').text(),
                    month: this.month + 1,
                    monthname: this.options.displayMonthAbbr ? this.options.monthabbrs[this.month] : this.options.months[this.month],
                    year: this.year,
                    weekday: idx + this.options.startIn,
                    weekdayname: this.options.weeks[(idx == 6 ? 0 : idx + this.options.startIn)]
                };

            $cell.children('div.fc-calendar-events').children('div.fc-calendar-event').each(function(i, e) {
                var $html = $('<div>' + $(e).html() + '</div>');
                data.startTime[i] = new Date($html.find('time.fc-starttime').attr('datetime'));
                data.endTime[i] = new Date($html.find('time.fc-endtime').attr('datetime'));
                data.allDay[i] = $html.find('time.fc-allday').attr('datetime') === 'true' ? true : false;
                $html.find('time').remove();
                data.content[i] = $html.html();
            });

            if (dateProp.day) this.options[event]($cell, data, dateProp);
        },

        _initEvents: function() {
            var self = this,
                event = [],
                calendarioEventNameFormat = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < self.options.events.length; i++) {
                event[i] = self.options.events[i].toLowerCase().trim();
                calendarioEventNameFormat[i] = 'onDay' + event[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + event[i].slice(1);

                if (this.options[calendarioEventNameFormat[i]] === undefined)
                    this.options[calendarioEventNameFormat[i]] = function($el, $content, dateProperties) {
                        return false;
                    };

                this.$el.on(event[i] + '.calendario', 'div.fc-row > div', function(e) {
                    if (e.type == 'mouseenter' || e.type == 'mouseleave') e.type = $.inArray(e.type, event) == -1 ? 'hover' : e.type;
                    self._propDate($(this), calendarioEventNameFormat[$.inArray(e.type, event)]);
                });
            }
            this.$el.on('shown.calendar.calendario', function(e, instance) {
                // If check update set to true, then contact calendario's update servers for details. We didn't want to slow down your code. So we
                // check after the calendar is rendered.
                if (instance && instance.options.checkUpdate) self._checkUpdate();
            });
            // newday trigger. This trigger is exactly triggered at 00:00 hours the next day with an uncertainty of 6ms.
            this.$el.delay(new Date(this.today.getFullYear(), this.today.getMonth(), this.today.getDate() + 1, 0, 0, 0) - new Date().getTime())
                .queue(function() {
                    self.today = new Date();
                    if (self.today.getMonth() == self.month || self.today.getMonth() + 1 == self.month) self._generateTemplate(true);
                    self.$el.trigger($.Event('newday.calendar.calendario'));
                });
        },

        _checkUpdate: function() {
            var self = this;
            $.getScript("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codrops/Calendario/master/js/update.js")
                .done(function(script, textStatus) {
                    if (calendario.current != self.version() && parseFloat(calendario.current) >= parseFloat(self.version()))
                        console.info(calendario.msg);
                })
                .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
                    console.error(exception);
                });
        },

        // Calendar logic based on http://jszen.blogspot.pt/2007/03/how-to-build-simple-calendar-with.html
        _generateTemplate: function(firstRun, callback) {
            var head = this._getHead(),
                body = this._getBody(),
                rowClass;

            switch (this.rowTotal) {
                case 2:
                    rowClass = 'fc-two-rows';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rowClass = 'fc-three-rows';
                    break;
                case 4:
                    rowClass = 'fc-four-rows';
                    break;
                case 5:
                    rowClass = 'fc-five-rows';
                    break;
                case 6:
                    rowClass = 'fc-six-rows';
                    break;
            }

            this.$cal = $('<div class="fc-calendar ' + rowClass + '">').append(head, body);
            this.$el.find('div.fc-calendar').remove().end().append(this.$cal);
            this.$el.find('.fc-emptydate').parent().css({
                'background': 'transparent',
                'cursor': 'default'
            });

            if (!firstRun) this.$el.trigger($.Event('shown.calendario'));
            if (callback) callback.call();
        },

        _getHead: function() {
            var html = '<div class="fc-head">';
            for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
                var pos = i + this.options.startIn,
                    j = pos > 6 ? pos - 6 - 1 : pos;
                html += '<div>' + (this.options.displayWeekAbbr ? this.options.weekabbrs[j] : this.options.weeks[j]) + '</div>';
            }
            return html + '</div>';
        },

        _parseDataToDay: function(data, day, other) {
            var content = '';
            if (!other) {
                if (Array.isArray(data)) content = this._convertDayArray(data, day);
                else content = this._wrapDay(data, day, true);
            } else {
                if (!Array.isArray(data)) data = [data];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (this.month != 1 && (day >= data[i].startDate) && (day <= data[i].endDate)) content += this._wrapDay(data[i], day, true);
                    else if (this.month == 1 && (day >= data[i].startDate)) {
                        if (data[i].endDate && (day <= data[i].endDate)) content += this._wrapDay(data[i], day, true);
                        else if (!data[i].endDate) content += this._wrapDay(data[i], day, true);
                    }
                }
            }
            return content;
        },

        _toDateTime: function(time, day, start) {
            var zoneH = parseInt(this.options.zone.split(':')[0]),
                zoneM = parseInt(this.options.zone.charAt(0) + this.options.zone.split(':')[1]),
                hour = parseInt(time.split(':')[0]) - zoneH,
                minutes = parseInt(time.split(':')[1]) - zoneM,
                d = new Date(Date.UTC(this.year, this.month, day, hour, minutes, 0, 0));
            if (start) {
                var hStart = parseInt(start.split(':')[0]) - zoneH,
                    mStart = parseInt(start.split(':')[1]) - zoneM;
                if (d.getTime() - new Date(Date.UTC(this.year, this.month, day, hStart, mStart, 0, 0)).getTime() < 0)
                    d = new Date(Date.UTC(this.year, this.month, day + 1, hour, minutes, 0, 0));
            }
            return d.toISOString();
        },

        _timeHtml: function(day, date) {
            var content = day.content;
            content += '<time class="fc-allday" datetime="' + day.allDay + '"></time>';
            content += '<time class="fc-starttime" datetime="' + this._toDateTime(day.startTime, date) + '">' + day.startTime + '</time>';
            content += '<time class="fc-endtime" datetime="' + this._toDateTime(day.endTime, date, day.startTime) + '">' + day.endTime + '</time>';
            return content;
        },

        _wrapDay: function(day, date, wrap) {
            if (date) {
                if (wrap) return '<div class="fc-calendar-event">' + this._timeHtml(day, date) + '</div>';
                else return this._timeHtml(day, date);
            } else return '<div class="fc-calendar-event">' + day + '</div>';
        },

        _convertDayArray: function(day, date) {
            var wrap_days = []
            for (var i = 0; i < day.length; i++) {
                wrap_days[i] = this._wrapDay(day[i], date, false);
            }
            return this._wrapDay(wrap_days.join('</div><div class="fc-calendar-event">'));
        },

        _getBody: function() {
            var d = new Date(this.year, this.month + 1, 0),
                monthLength = d.getDate(), // number of days in the month
                firstDay = new Date(this.year, d.getMonth(), 1),
                pMonthLength = new Date(this.year, this.month, 0).getDate();

            // day of the week
            this.startingDay = firstDay.getDay();

            var html = '<div class="fc-body"><div class="fc-row">',
                day = 1; // fill in the days

            for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) { // this loop is for weeks (rows)
                for (var j = 0; j <= 6; j++) { // this loop is for weekdays (cells)
                    var pos = this.startingDay - this.options.startIn,
                        p = pos < 0 ? 6 + pos + 1 : pos,
                        inner = '',
                        today = this.month === this.today.getMonth() && this.year === this.today.getFullYear() && day === this.today.getDate(),
                        past = this.year < this.today.getFullYear() || this.month < this.today.getMonth() && this.year === this.today.getFullYear() ||
                        this.month === this.today.getMonth() && this.year === this.today.getFullYear() && day < this.today.getDate(),
                        content = '';

                    if (this.options.fillEmpty && (j < p || i > 0)) {
                        if (day > monthLength) {
                            inner = '<span class="fc-date fc-emptydate">' + (day - monthLength) + '</span><span class="fc-weekday">';
                            ++day;
                        } else if (day == 1) {
                            inner = '<span class="fc-date fc-emptydate">' + (pMonthLength - p + 1) + '</span><span class="fc-weekday">';
                            ++pMonthLength;
                        }
                        inner += this.options.weekabbrs[j + this.options.startIn > 6 ? j + this.options.startIn - 6 - 1 : j + this.options.startIn] + '</span>';
                    }
                    if (day <= monthLength && (i > 0 || j >= p)) {
                        inner = '<span class="fc-date">' + day + '</span><span class="fc-weekday">' + this.options.weekabbrs[j +
                            this.options.startIn > 6 ? j + this.options.startIn - 6 - 1 : j + this.options.startIn] + '</span>';

                        var strdate = (this.month + 1 < 10 ? '0' + (this.month + 1) : this.month + 1) + '-' + (day < 10 ? '0' + day : day) + '-' + this.year,
                            dayData = this.caldata[strdate],
                            strdateyear = (this.month + 1 < 10 ? '0' + (this.month + 1) : this.month + 1) + '-' + (day < 10 ? '0' + day : day) + '-YYYY',
                            dayDataYear = this.caldata[strdateyear],
                            strdatemonth = 'MM-' + (day < 10 ? '0' + day : day) + '-' + this.year,
                            dayDataMonth = this.caldata[strdatemonth],
                            strdatemonthyear = 'MM' + '-' + (day < 10 ? '0' + day : day) + '-YYYY',
                            dayDataMonthYear = this.caldata[strdatemonthyear],
                            strdatemonthlyyear = (this.month + 1 < 10 ? '0' + (this.month + 1) : this.month + 1) + '-DD-' + this.year,
                            dayDataMonthlyYear = this.caldata[strdatemonthlyyear],
                            strdatemonthly = (this.month + 1 < 10 ? '0' + (this.month + 1) : this.month + 1) + '-DD-YYYY',
                            dayDataMonthly = this.caldata[strdatemonthly];

                        if (today && this.caldata.TODAY) content += this._parseDataToDay(this.caldata.TODAY, day);
                        if (dayData) content += this._parseDataToDay(dayData, day);
                        if (dayDataMonth) content += this._parseDataToDay(dayDataMonth, day);
                        if (dayDataMonthlyYear) content += this._parseDataToDay(dayDataMonthlyYear, day, true);
                        if (dayDataMonthly) content += this._parseDataToDay(dayDataMonthly, day, true);
                        if (dayDataMonthYear) content += this._parseDataToDay(dayDataMonthYear, day);
                        if (dayDataYear) content += this._parseDataToDay(dayDataYear, day);
                        if (content !== '') inner += '<div class="fc-calendar-events">' + content + '</div>';
                        ++day;
                    } else {
                        today = false;
                    }

                    var cellClasses = today ? 'fc-today ' : '';

                    if (past) cellClasses += 'fc-past ';
                    else cellClasses += 'fc-future ';

                    if (content !== '') cellClasses += 'fc-content';

                    html += (cellClasses !== '' ? '<div class="' + cellClasses.trim() + '">' : '<div>') + inner + '</div>';
                }

                if (day > monthLength) { // stop making rows if we've run out of days
                    this.rowTotal = i + 1;
                    break;
                } else {
                    html += '</div><div class="fc-row">';
                }
            }
            return html + '</div></div>';
        },

        _move: function(period, dir, callback) {
            if (dir === 'previous') {
                if (period === 'month') {
                    this.year = this.month > 0 ? this.year : --this.year;
                    this.month = this.month > 0 ? --this.month : 11;
                } else if (period === 'year') this.year = --this.year;
            } else if (dir === 'next') {
                if (period === 'month') {
                    this.year = this.month < 11 ? this.year : ++this.year;
                    this.month = this.month < 11 ? ++this.month : 0;
                } else if (period === 'year') this.year = ++this.year;
            }
            this._generateTemplate(false, callback);
        },

        /************************* 
         ***** PUBLIC METHODS *****
         **************************/
        option: function(option, value) {
            if (value) this.options[option] = value;
            else return this.options[option];
        },
        getYear: function() {
            return this.year;
        },
        getMonth: function() {
            return this.month + 1;
        },
        getMonthName: function() {
            return this.options.displayMonthAbbr ? this.options.monthabbrs[this.month] : this.options.months[this.month];
        },
        // gets the cell's content div associated to a day of the current displayed month
        // day : 1 - [28||29||30||31]
        getCell: function(day) {
            var row = Math.floor((day + this.startingDay - this.options.startIn - 1) / 7),
                pos = day + this.startingDay - this.options.startIn - (row * 7) - 1;
            return this.$cal.find('div.fc-body').children('div.fc-row').eq(row).children('div').eq(pos);
        },
        setData: function(caldata, clear) {
            caldata = this._processCaldata(caldata);
            if (clear) this.caldata = caldata;
            else $.extend(this.caldata, caldata);
            this._generateTemplate(false);
        },
        // goes to today's month/year
        gotoNow: function(callback) {
            this.month = this.today.getMonth();
            this.year = this.today.getFullYear();
            this._generateTemplate(false, callback);
        },
        // goes to month/year
        gotoMonth: function(month, year, callback) {
            this.month = month - 1;
            this.year = year;
            this._generateTemplate(false, callback);
        },
        gotoPreviousMonth: function(callback) {
            this._move('month', 'previous', callback);
        },
        gotoPreviousYear: function(callback) {
            this._move('year', 'previous', callback);
        },
        gotoNextMonth: function(callback) {
            this._move('month', 'next', callback);
        },
        gotoNextYear: function(callback) {
            this._move('year', 'next', callback);
        },
        feed: function(callback) {
            var self = this;
            $.post(self.options.feedParser, {
                    dates: this.caldata
                })
                .always(function(data) {
                    if (callback) callback.call(this, JSON.parse(data).hevent);
                });
        },
        version: function() {
            return this.VERSION;
        }
    };

    var logError = function(message) {
        throw new Error(message);
    };

    $.fn.calendario = function(options) {
        var instance = $.data(this, 'calendario');
        if (typeof options === 'string') {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
            this.each(function() {
                if (!instance) {
                    logError("Cannot call methods on calendario prior to initialization; Attempted to call method '" + options + "'");
                    return;
                }
                if (!$.isFunction(instance[options]) || options.charAt(0) === "_") {
                    logError("No such method '" + options + "' for calendario instance.");
                }
                instance[options].apply(instance, args);
            });
        } else {
            this.each(function() {
                if (instance) instance._init();
                else instance = $.data(this, 'calendario', new $.Calendario(options, this));
            });
        }
        instance.$el.trigger($.Event('shown.calendar.calendario'), [instance]);
        return instance;
    };
})(jQuery, window);
```

Comment: You should try not to post your entire Javascript file, but instead post a minimal version of where you are having a problem. In this case, you could post only the portion of the code that is handling this *Calendario*. If you absolutely need all of your code, then create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Also, please put a link to the plugin you are using so that we can review the documentation to help you.

Comment: well here is the link to their github https://github.com/codrops/Calendario/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can yet - Developer of the version you posted, better version available at https://github.com/deviprsd21/Calendario

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation to comment.